# Force browser to use higher security connection

Tags: encryption, tls, web-browser

How can I force my Chrome broswer (or even Firefox) to always use a higher security encryption?, for example 256bit (or more) encryption when using https.
I guess it should be some flag to force the negotiation.
I know it also depends on the other side of the connection.
I'm using Windows 7.

regards

Answer (score 3):

As indicated in [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/38731/5411), you can blacklist some SSL/TLS cipher suites with a command-line argument. Use [SSL Labs client test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html) to see what your browser is currently supporting, then close it and launch it again from the command-line with all the cipher suites you don't like deactivated.

Of course, not supporting some cipher suites may imply not being able to connect with some sites. For a SSL connection to succeed, both client and server must have at least one cipher suite they both support.

Also, [128 bits for symmetric keys are fine](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6141/amount-of-simple-operations-that-is-safely-out-of-reach-for-all-humanity/6149#6149). Requiring "the biggest keys" is like buying a truck because you think that bigger cars are always better, and a 40-ton truck is undoubtedly bigger than a car. The next time you have to park your truck or pay for gas, you might somehow modify your opinion...

Comment: What about enabling QUIC and SPDY/4 flags?