# Add Cipher Suite support to Chrome/ Chromoium?

Tags: cipher-selection, install

I would like to know how to add Cipher Suite: `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` support to the new versions of Chrome?
Since Chrome v25/26 Google stopped the support of Cipher Suite: `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA`. Unfortunately, I am working on application that require such a cipher and for that I have built a kind of Extension/Addon for it on Chrome. Without the support of this cipher my addon/extension will be useless.

Does anybody how to fix such an issue?

I have used the following command
chrome.exe --cipher-suite-blacklist=0xc007,0xc011,0x0066,0xc00c,0xc002,0x0005,0x0004

then I checked my browser SSL support using this website:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html

but I still can't get my application to work. Is there anything I missed? is the cipher order matters?

Comment: 1.) It's bizarre to see an application limited to a single cipher suite, 2.) [As far as I can tell](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewClient.html?name=Chrome&version=37&platform=OS%20X), Chrome still supports that cipher suite.

Comment: SuiteB specs are highly restrictive, and limit to just a few ciphers.

Answer (score 3):

Cipher suites are removed or added by Google through software patches or updates.  You can blacklist cipher suites by adding a command-line argument to Chrome's startup; as [shown in this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/38731/52676).  Hexadecimal values for each cipher suite can be [found here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4).

There isn't any functionality for enabling non-default cipher suites.  I believe you might be stuck with changing your application's cipher suite to a newly supported cipher suite.

Here is the [most recent issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=282457) I could find.