# What's the impact of POODLE to the Internet?

Tags: tls

POODLE can be exploited on SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0, as the latter falls back to SSL 3 after multiple connection errors. I wonder how many use these protocols for encrypted data transfer, will it be a major internet security issue?

Comment: this question is already addressed in this one right here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70719/ssl3-poodle-vulnerability and is also completely explained by the top experts in SEC.SE ;)

Comment: Vote to close as duplicate.