# How do I use "openssl s_client" to test for (absence of) SSLv3 support?

Tags: tls, openssl

In order to mitigate the ["Poodle" vulnerability](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/70719/27877), I'd like to disable SSLv3 support in my (in this case, TLS, rather than HTTPS) server. How can I use `openssl s_client` to verify that I've done this?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

## OpenSSL s_client

To check if you have disabled the SSLv3 support, then run the following

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -ssl3
```

which should produce something like

```
3073927320:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1258:SSL alert number 40
3073927320:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:596:
```

meaning SSLv3 is disabled on the server.  Otherwise the connection will established successfully.

## Nmap

Alternatively, you can **use nmap** to scan server for supported version:

```
# nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers example.com
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-10-15 03:19 PDT
Nmap scan report for example.com (203.0.113.100)
Host is up (0.090s latency).
rDNS record for 203.0.113.100: edge.example.com
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   **SSLv3: No supported ciphers found**
|   TLSv1.0:
```

Comment: The openssl command works; I can't get the nmap script to work, though.

Comment: Ah. Non-default port. Use `--script +ssl-enum-ciphers`, per http://stackoverflow.com/a/17175548/8446.

Comment: What is the output of your nmap command ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rlipscombe/eb941f08f24016fe5cd0

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Right, so what's not working there? SSLv3 is not listed, so it's not supported.

Comment: It's working fine; I solved it. I'm using a non-standard port, so I have to prefix the script name with '+' to force it to run.

Comment: See also this answer to know how to interpret the openssl output: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/169738/60157

Answer (score 39):

On a side note you can use `nmap` with ssl-enum-ciphers script as follows

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 example.com
```

You will get a response like this.

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   SSLv3: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA - strong
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|   TLSv1.0: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA - strong
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|   TLSv1.1: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 - strong
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|_  least strength: strong
```

As you can see it lists all the supported versions of ssl/tls as well as the cipher suites

Comment: Simply the fastest way to get a list of available ciphers on a remote endpoint. nmap rules, as usual! ;)

Answer (score 6):

I created this test for the availability of the SSLv3 protocol. There is probably a better way to search for a string that also shows that CBC ciphers are in use, but most people just seem to want to know if SSLv3 is available at all.

A few things to note:

- Written for the bash on Mac OS X so can't say for sure it will work everywhere
- Uses gtimeout vs. timeout since Mac is weird about those core utils
- allexternal.txt is a file with one hostname or IP per line

script:

```
for ip in `awk '{print $1}' < allexternal.txt`; do
    if gtimeout 30 openssl s_client -connect $ip:443 -ssl3 | grep -q 'Protocol  : SSLv3' ; then
        echo $ip SSLv3 detected >> sslv3output;
    else
        echo $ip SSLv3 NOT detected >> sslv3output;
    fi;
done
```

Comment: Apologies for the formatting, wasn't sure how to have grave accents show up as literal instead of making it into a code block.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but can I suggest you use echo 'QUIT' so you don't have to install gtimeout.  The second line should read...  if echo 'QUIT' | openssl s_client -connect $ip:443 -ssl3 | grep -q 'Protocol  : SSLv3' ; then

Comment: Using "Protocol  : SSLv3" also seems to be dubious.  Per this page: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/71459/51963, "Cipher    : 0000" may be a better string to search for.

Answer (score 6):

If just SSLv3 is disabled, you can also force `openssl s_client` to use only TLS:

```
openssl s_client -connect exmaple.com:443 -tls1
```

Comment: For TLS 1.0 and above, you should use the `-servername` option too. In enlists SNI.

Comment: This does not verify that ssl3 is disable, it just tells to use TLS 1

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that the -ssl3 option in OpenSSL now has to be enabled at compile time.  If you're running on pre-compiled binaries then the option may not be available.  See this issue:  https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/6801

An alternative tool is testssl.sh.  This checks for protocols, ciphers and selected vulnerabilities:  https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh