# How to manually test for DROWN attack?

Tags: openssl

We know that the official website serves the user with a way to test our servers against DROWN attack. Apart from that, I am looking for a manual testing method to check any servers against this vulnerability. I found some methods to test POODLE [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70733/how-do-i-use-openssl-s-client-to-test-for-absence-of-sslv3-support/70737#70737). I am looking for something similar.

Comment: https://github.com/nimia/public_drown_scanner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to manually confirm the results:

1- Using nmap:

```
nmap -sV -sC [IP]
```

2- Using SSLyze

```
sslyze --sslv2 [IP]
```

3- Using Google SSLScan

```
sslscan --no-failed [IP]
```

4- Directly with openSSL

```
openssl s_client -no_tls1 -no_ssl3 -connect [IP]
```

5- Externally-accessible hosts can be tested with

`https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/`

Make sure you have SSLv2 enabled on your machine. For more information, please see http://www.softwaresecured.com/2016/03/01/how-to-confirm-whether-you-are-vulnerable-to-the-drown-attack/