# Disable SSLv3 system-wide for all clients?

Tags: tls, linux

After reading about [Poodle secutrity bug](http://www.google.cz/url?q=https://www.openssl.org/~bodo/ssl-poodle.pdf), I have disabled SSLv3 on my
servers and browsers.

But there are several clients that do not expose settings detailed enough
via their own means of configuration, e.g. owncloud, uzbl-browser.  Also,
come to think about it, it is kind of cumbersome to go through every single
client...

Apart from rebuilding SSL libraries they use, is there way how to set up
a system-wide default or a policy for simplistic (or "irresponsible", if
you want) clients like that?

I was kind of expecting to find something in /etc/ssl but that only seems
to address certificates and autorities.

Comment: The simple answer is no, unfortunately this is not possible.

Comment: Because Poodle relies on adaptive chosen plaintext, it's really only web browsers that are vulnerable, which should reduce your workload a little

Comment: @paj28 That's not accurate, not just browsers go through HTTPS (HTTP API's, for example).

Comment: @Robert - Only browsers are vulnerable to Poodle. See  [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70719/ssl3-poodle-vulnerability) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Its possible to make changes to the TCP/IP SSL levels, but not really considered a policy per say, You might be able to use a deployment service to make the changes using AutoIT (I make company wide changes with this as my deployment asset.

Answer (score 1):

If you implement SSL-proxying, you can configure your proxy server (e.g. Squid) to not use SSLv3 to any side of the connection (client-to-proxy and proxy-to-web).