# Windows OLE Vulnerability CVE-2014-4114 "Sandworm"

Tags: windows, known-vulnerabilities, vulnerability

Just heard about a new vulnerability and am using the same format as [the POODLE guy](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70719/ssl3-poodle-vulnerability) for this one.

1. What is the Sandworm vulnerability?
2. I use [product/browser]. Am I affected?
3. Is [product] vulnerable to the Sandworm attack?
4. What do I need to do to secure my [product] with respect to this
           vulnerability?
5. How do I detect Sandworm attacks on my network?
6. Are
           there any known Sandworm attacks?

References:

- http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/sandworm-windows-zero-day-vulnerability-being-actively-exploited-targeted-attacks
- https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-4114

Comment: Sandworm is not the name of the vulnerability.  It's the name of a hacking campaign that happened to take advantage of CVE-2014-4114.

Comment: @Xander Yes, I saw that also in the Symantec article, but as the story has spread, it has gained that name. At least the two emails I got from different security vendors mentioned it as "The Sandworm" Vulnerability. Also I heard there was a hacker named 4chan the got a bunch of celebrity pictures...

Comment: Ha!  Yes, that is quite true.