# RC4 encryption of torrents safely

Tags: encryption, rc4, torrent

Torrent clients offer encryption of traffic using RC4, and people consider this very safe to hide traffic information from ISP.

Now since I have a website with SSL encryption, I know that RC4 has a vulnerability. But does this apply to torrents encryption?

How safe is it to encrypt torrent traffic with RC4?

Comment: The vulnerability you're referencing is with SSL, not RC4.  So the fact that RC4 is being used does not inherently mean that the encryption is unsafe.

Comment: @raz May I ask, if the problem is with SSL, and not RC4, why can't it be fixed?

Comment: It seems I was wrong.  This [question and answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32497/tls-rc4-or-not-rc4) discuss the RC4 issues.  For others reading this question.

Comment: Not only is the RC4 itself a weak cipher, but the key exchange method itself is only 60-80 bits in strength, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_protocol_encryption#Security. I also remember reading that part of the key comes from the infohash, which is public information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Torrent clients offer encryption of traffic using RC4, and **people consider this, like, very safe** to hide traffic information from ISP.

People are wrong to do so, but not because RC4 is even remotely the weak point. Simply knowing which IPs you're connecting to allows precise determination of the torrent you are downloading by an opponent who simply scrapes trackers or DHT to determine which IPs are in which swarms. This is leaving aside the even bigger problem of your torrent client actively -publishing- your IP in these lists to allow other peers to discover it.