# OpenSSL: Enable cipher suites per protocol version

Tags: tls, openssl, beast

Is there a way to explicitly configure OpenSSL to allow AES (or in general, block ciphers) only for clients that use a TLS version >= 1.1?

This would protect against the BEAST attack, while still allowing the use of ciphers more secure than the ancient RC4.

The [suggested workaround for OpenSSL](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17080/is-there-a-way-to-mitigate-beast-without-disabling-aes-completely) (enforce the server's cipher preference order; prefer AES-GCM over RC4 over AES-CBC) excludes all clients that don't support the GCM cipher suites, even though they are perfectly capable of securely using AES-CBC due to the fixes in TLS 1.1.

It seems that many popular sites have opted to just use RC4 for everything, which doesn't seem like a really good idea (RC4 has many known weaknesses, and many TLS implementations [have workarounds even for TLS <= 1.1](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/24489/5701)). I wonder if a server-side "use AES, but only if it's safe"-flag could improve the situation.

Comment: Even most 1.0 clients have workarounds for BEAST. So for a webapplication I'd go with AES-CBC even with TLS 1.0. Clients which are so old and unpatched that they're vulnerable to BEAST, are probably vulnerable to dozens of remote code execution vulnerabilities.

Comment: I definitely agree; however, at least one popular SSL setup security validation/certification service didn't (for quite a while, they used to penalize any vulnerable cipher suites in their checks). Meanwhile, they've changed their opinion and now penalize RC4 instead... Also, Google seems to trust RC4 more than AES-CBC - at least, that's what they select for Google Chrome in my experience.

Answer (score 4):

From a cursory look in OpenSSL's source code, no, the library is not up to what you want. The cipher suite selection appears to be done in `ssl3_choose_cipher()` (in `ssl/s3_lib.c`) and that function works with a list of "supported cipher suites". The list is *pruned* depending on the negotiated version (OpenSSL won't select a cipher suite which is not supported for the version which will be used), but the list does not contain version-specific preferences.

Programmatically, it would be possible to make an input filter on incoming data, which recognizes a `ClientHello` message, and dynamically adjusts OpenSSL settings based on the maximum version announced in that message. This would be a rather terrifying hack, which would "just work". However, you won't have that with configuration only.

At least the [protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) supports what you wish to obtain. This would not be true in the opposite direction: since the client announces in one message the maximum version it accepts *and* the list of cipher suites it supports, there is no way for the client to say "AES-CBC, but only for TLS 1.1+".